# process back button press when loading web page

Tags: android-intent

I am having problems with the back button in android and need some help.

My application has an activity named 'A'. 
From 'A', I start new activity named 'B' but don't finish 'A'. 
From 'B', I start new intent to call web browser. 
When a user press the back button while the webpage loading isn't complete, it causes my program back to activity 'B'. 
However I don't want to back to activity 'B', I want to finish B and back to activity 'A' instead.

Does anyone have a solution for this situation? Please help me!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

yOU CAN OVERRIDE THE  following method

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```